# Spark: Executor Lost Failure (After adding groupBy job)

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, out-of-memory, executors

I’m trying to run Spark job on Yarn client. I have two nodes and each node has the following configurations.
[image]

I’m getting  “ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 lost)”.

I have tried most of the Spark tuning configuration. I have reduced to one executor lost because initially I got like 6 executor failures.

These are my configuration (my spark-submit) :

> HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs spark-submit --class genkvs.CreateFieldMappings
>   --master yarn-client --driver-memory 11g --executor-memory 11G --total-executor-cores 16 --num-executors 15 --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseCompressedOops
>   -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps" --conf spark.akka.frameSize=1000 --conf spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=1 --conf
>   spark.rdd.compress=true --conf
>   spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout=800
>   my-data/lookup_cache_spark-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -h
>   hdfs://hdp-node-1.zone24x7.lk:8020 -p 800

My data size is 6GB and I’m doing a groupBy in my job.

```
def process(in: RDD[(String, String, Int, String)]) = {
    in.groupBy(_._4)
}
```

I’m new to Spark, please help me to find my mistake. I’m struggling for at least a week now.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues pop out:

- the spark.shuffle.memoryFraction is set to 1. Why did you choose that instead of leaving the default 0.2 ?  That may starve other non shuffle operations
- You only have 11G available to 16 cores. With only 11G I would set the number of workers in your job to no more than 3 - and initially (to get past the executors lost issue) just try 1.  With 16 executors each one gets like 700mb - which then no surprise they are getting OOME / executor lost.

Comment: Initially I got this following error :Missing an output location for shuffle 0. So I got to know I need to increase my shuffle memory fraction. Ok thanks for your suggestions. I will try and get back to you.

Comment: still it fails - Spark: Executor Lost Failure

Comment: when I go through the stack it shows : spark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space exception. I think because of this reason it's loosing the executors. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I mentioned that in the answer to try a *single* executor. You don't have enough memory available to the cluster in general.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Even with single executor same issue.

Comment: ok please check the spark gui to ensure the executor were receiving all 11GB

Comment: I’m bit confused. In my spark-history, it shows used memory as 0. Please check these images and help me to understand this problem.  Link: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7B0DM8X9cfQU19DendRb2FXU1k&usp=sharing

Comment: Failure reason says "Failed to open FileSegmentManagedBuffer".  That sounds like a completely different issue: either hdfs or local file system permissions.

Comment: Yes. It was the security issue. Thanks a lot :). Now executor is failing due to akka timeout. I have given spark.akka.frameSize=1000. But still, it's failing. Any thoughts about it ?

Comment: Did you try this:  spark.akka.timeout

Comment: Yes actually I tried all these conf: --conf spark.worker.timeout=30000 --conf spark.akka.timeout=30000 --conf spark.storage.blockManagerHeartBeatMs=30000  --conf spark.akka.retry.wait=30000 --conf spark.akka.frameSize=2047

Comment: Sorry no further ideas at this time.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Really appreciate your help. I have requested to increase my server's RAM to 32GB. Hope it will help to execute my jobs.

Comment: I modified my code to 'reduceByKey' and it worked. Just wanted to share with you @javadba. After reading this blog : http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/. I modified and tried it.

Comment: OK, thx for sending that back.  I know about reduceByKey vs groupByKey but it does point to not enough memory. You changed the nature of the problem by optimizing it to require less resources.